# lenevo thinkpad 11e password reset

Tags: boot, bios, password-recovery

I have a Yoga 11e Thinkpad laptop and I can't make any choices in the BIOS.

It asks for a password, and if you answer incorrectly 3 times it lets you into the BIOS but you can't make any changes.

If I let it boot up all the way a screen pops up that gives me choices to choose like boot manager , ata hddo:, and pci lan , setup, diagnostic splash screen, and lenevo diagnostics but it won't let me choose any of the choices.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to superuser.com! Please use proper grammar and formatting when asking a question. As it stands, your question is very hard to read. Also, please provide some context: What is on that laptop? Do you want to retrieve data? Do you want to reinstall it? Do you have the BIOS code?

Comment: i dont have the bios code it shows a little lock and if u miss it three times it lets u in the bios but u cant make changes how or what can i do to make changes to the bios after i get in it

Comment: im trying to erase everything on it so i can put my own os on it but i cant perform anything on it

Comment: We'd like to help you, but there are some rules here. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask , then edit your question. Also, please do not add corrections in comments, edit the question instead.

Comment: can u please tell me how to wipe this machine clean from start up (completely) remove all previous data

Comment: Did you read my last comment? Please play by the rules and edit your question, otherwise it will be closed

Comment: im kinda wondering if i had the code thats what u asked i wouldent be asking u any of this cause none of these problems would be so of course i dont have the bios code do u think u could give me some help in not needing or making it dissaper or put in a default something that would make the laptop go passed it if i had the code it askes for i could change things inthe bios but if i fail to provide that code and miss it three time it will let me in the bios but i cant change any values in it cause i dident provide the code so it teases me lets me in but all i can do is go through it

Comment: and sorry if my spelling is a little of but i would hope u still know what im saying

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I remove the BIOS passwords?

There are 3 kinds of passwords. It is not clear from your question which one you need to remove.

> As many as three passwords may be needed for any ThinkPad notebook
>   computer: the power-on password, the hard disk password, and the
>   supervisor password.
>
> If any of these passwords has been set, a prompt for it will be
>   displayed on the screen whenever the computer is turned on. The
>   computer does not start until the password is entered.
>
> Note: If only a supervisor password is set, the password prompt will
>   not be displayed when the operating system is started.
>
> **Power-on password**
>
> A power-on password protects the system from being powered on by an
>   unauthorized person. The password must be entered before an operating
>   system can be started. For instructions on how to remove the power-on
>   password, see “How to remove the power-on password” on page 33.
>
> **Hard disk password**
>
> There are two kinds of hard disk passwords:
>
> - User hard disk password - for the user
> - Master hard disk password - for the system administrator, who can use it to get access to the hard disk even if the user has changed the
>     user hard disk password
>
> Note: There are two modes for the hard disk password: User only and
>   Master + User. The Master + User mode requires two hard disk
>   passwords; the system administrator enters both in the same operation.
>   The system administrator then provides the user hard disk password to
>   the system user.
>
> Attention: If the user hard disk password has been forgotten, check
>   whether a master hard disk password has been set. If it has, it can be
>   used for access to the hard disk drive. If no master hard disk
>   password is available, neither Lenovo nor Lenovo authorized service
>   technicians provide any services to reset either the user or the
>   master hard disk password, or to recover data from the hard disk
>   drive. The hard disk drive can be replaced for a scheduled fee.
>
> For how to remove the hard disk password, see “How to remove the hard
>   disk password” on page 34.
>
> **Supervisor password**
>
> A supervisor password protects the system information stored in the
>   ThinkPad Setup. The user must enter the supervisor password in order
>   to get access to the ThinkPad Setup and change the system
>   configuration.
>
> Attention: If the supervisor password has been forgotten and cannot be
>   made available to the service technician, there is no service
>   procedure to reset the password. The system board must be replaced for
>   a scheduled fee.
>
> **How to remove the power-on password**
>
> To remove a power-on password, do the following:
>
> If no supervisor password has been set, do the following to remove the
>   power-on password:
>
> 1. Turn off the computer and disconnect ac power.
> 2. Disable the built-in battery. See “Disabling the built-in battery” on page 54.
> 3. Remove the bottom cover. See “1010 Bottom cover” on page 54.
> 4. Remove the coin-cell battery and wait for a few seconds. See “1060 Coin-cell battery” on page 60.
> 5. Reinstall the coin-call battery.
> 6. Reinstall the bottom cover.
> 7. Reconnect ac power.
> 8. Turn on the computer and wait until the POST ends. After the POST ends, the password prompt does not appear. The power-on password has
>      been removed.
>
> If a supervisor password has been set and is known to the service
>   technician, do the following to remove the power-on password:
>
> 1. Turn on the computer.
> 2. When the ThinkPad logo is displayed, immediately press F1.
> 3. Type the supervisor password to enter the ThinkPad Setup program.
> 4. Select Security.
> 5. Select Password.
> 6. Select Power-On Password.
> 7. Type the current supervisor password in the Enter Current Password field. Then leave the Enter New Password field blank, and press Enter
>      twice.
> 8. In the Changes have been saved window, press Enter. Press F10 to save changes and exit the ThinkPad Setup program. The power-on
>      password has been removed.
>
> **How to remove the hard disk password**
>
> Attention: If User only mode is selected and the user hard disk
>   password has been forgotten and cannot be made available to the
>   service technician, neither Lenovo nor Lenovo authorized service
>   technicians provide any services to reset the user hard disk passwords
>   or to recover data from the hard disk drive. The hard disk drive can
>   be replaced for a scheduled fee.
>
> To remove a user hard disk password that has been forgotten, when the
>   supervisor password and master hard disk password are known, do the
>   following:
>
> 1. Turn on the computer.
> 2. When the ThinkPad logo comes up, immediately press F1 to enter the ThinkPad Setup program. When the power-on password icon is displayed
>      on the screen, enter either the power-on password or the supervisor
>      password.
> 3. When the user hard disk password icon is displayed on the screen, press F1. The master hard disk password icon is displayed.
> 4. Enter the master hard disk password to enter the ThinkPad Setup program.
> 5. Select Security.
> 6. Select Password.
> 7. Select Hard-disk x password, where x is the letter of the hard disk drive. A pop-up window opens.
> 8. Select Master hard disk password.
> 9. Type the current master hard disk password in the Enter Current Password field. Then leave the Enter New Password field blank, and
>      press Enter twice.
> 10. Press F10 to save changes and exit the ThinkPad Setup program. The user hard disk password and the master hard disk password have been
>       removed.

Source [ThinkPad 11e and ThinkPad Yoga 11e Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://thinkpads.com/support/hmm/hmm_pdf/tp_11e_yoga11e_hmm_en_sp40f29949.pdf)

Comment: HI David, I appreciate that you are trying to help. However, I'm not sure it's a good to answer such poorly asked questions - I'm afraid that sets a bad precedent. I see you also fixed the question, I'm just not sure if this is not a case of "putting lipstick on a pig"...

Comment: when i power up the unit and press f 1 it takes me to a little lock in the top left hand corner and gives u 3 chances to give it thats what i need to get around

Comment: @sleske We are here to help. Not all users are native English speakers ...

Comment: and yes i do appreciate your taking time to help me but im so going crazy with this thing and its stressing me to the limit so i do thank your comments even if it doesent sound like it

Comment: @DavidPostill: Of course not (I'm not a native speaker either), but I don't think that's the problem here. Anyway, this question seems to be resolved. Maybe it's worth discussing this on meta at some point...

Comment: @user755324 The instructions are in the answer. Please read it again carefully.

Comment: i removed the button battery for at least 5 min and it did not help

Comment: @user755324 Then you have a supervisor password: "If the supervisor password has been forgotten and cannot be made available to the service technician, there is no service procedure to reset the password. The system board must be replaced for a scheduled fee."

Comment: it is a uefi bios version1.09 there is a uefi secure boot and its enabeld

Comment: @user755324 (*shrug*) I can't give you any more help. What I know is in the answer.